# Where command, XML Feed Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xml, linq, windows-phone-8

I can get the following feed to work without the where command, when I put the where command in I am not able to get it to work.

The 1231 is the value that routeId can be and is the value that routeId will be when it gets to the select command.

Any reason why this is failing?

Have also tried:

```
where s.Element("routeId").Value.Contains("1231")
```

And

```
where s.Attribute("routeId").Value == "1231"
```

and

```
where s.Element("routeId").Value == ("1231")
```

current code:

```
var routeNames = (from n in doc.Descendants(ns + "Service") 
                    select new RootContainer
                    {
                        Service = (from s in n.Element(ns + "routes").Elements(ns + "Route")
                        // where (n.Elements(ns + "timetables").Elements(ns + "Timetable").Elements(ns + "daysOfWeek").ToString() == "Sundays and Public Holidays from 14 September")

                        where s.Element("routeId").Value == "1231"
                        select new Services
                        {
                            RouteName = s.Element(ns + "routeName").Value, RouteId = s.Element(ns + "routeId").Value,
                            // Routes = s.Element(ns + "routeId").Attribute("1231").Value


                            //  TimetableName = s.Element(ns + "timetables").Element(ns + "Timetable").Element(ns + "daysOfWeek").Value,


                        }).ToList()

                    }).First();
```

This is the full XML.

My Aim is to get each of the Timetables: Monday to Fridays, Saturdays and Sundays... Or words to the effect, as this changes (what contains) from this feed

```
   <Service z:Id="i1" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BusExpress.ClassLibrary"    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">

 <routes>
  <Route z:Id="i4">
     <routeId>1231</routeId>
  <routeMap>
    <RouteMap z:Id="i6">

      <routeLineCenterLat>50.82754</routeLineCenterLat>
      <routeLineCenterLng>-0.166640326</routeLineCenterLng>
      <routeLineColour>#0000FF</routeLineColour>
      <routeLineFilename i:nil="true" />
      <routeLineInitialZoom>12</routeLineInitialZoom>
      <routeMapId>379</routeMapId>
      <routeMapName>1 Whitehawk - Mile Oak</routeMapName>
     </RouteMap>
  </routeMap>
  <routeName>1 Whitehawk - Mile Oak</routeName>
  <route_stop />
  <route_stop_stop />
  <route_stop_timetable_stop />
  <service z:Ref="i1" />
   <timetables>
    <Timetable z:Id="i8">
      <dateAdded>2013-08-27T13:22:26.703</dateAdded>
      <daysOfWeek>Sundays and Public Holidays</daysOfWeek>
      <isLive>false</isLive>
      <relativePosition>2</relativePosition>
      <route z:Ref="i4" />
      <route_stop_timetable_stop />
      <timetableDescription>Whitehawk - County Hospital - Brighton - Hove - Portslade - Mile Oak</timetableDescription>
      <timetableFilename>timetable_635132065412586254_0.xml</timetableFilename>
      <timetableId>10121</timetableId>
      <timetableName>1 1A Whitehawk - Mile Oak</timetableName>
      <timetable_stop />
      <validDates i:nil="true" />
    </Timetable>
    <Timetable z:Id="i10">
       <dateAdded>2014-03-26T13:09:06.233</dateAdded>
      <daysOfWeek>Mondays to Fridays</daysOfWeek>
      <isLive>false</isLive>
      <relativePosition>0</relativePosition>
      <route z:Ref="i4" />
      <routeReference xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses">
        <a:EntityKey z:Ref="i5" xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data" />
      </routeReference>
      <route_stop_timetable_stop />
      <timetableDescription>Whitehawk - County Hospital - Brighton - Hove - Portslade - Mile Oak</timetableDescription>
      <timetableFilename>timetable_635314361366540988_0.xml</timetableFilename>
      <timetableId>10315</timetableId>
      <timetableName>1 1A Whitehawk - Mile Oak</timetableName>
      <timetable_stop />
      <validDates />
    </Timetable>
    <Timetable z:Id="i12">
      <dateAdded>2014-03-26T13:09:53.017</dateAdded>
      <daysOfWeek>Saturdays</daysOfWeek>
      <isLive>false</isLive>
      <relativePosition>1</relativePosition>
      <route z:Ref="i4" />
      <routeReference xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses">
        <a:EntityKey z:Ref="i5" xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data" />
      </routeReference>
      <route_stop_timetable_stop />
      <timetableDescription>Whitehawk - County Hospital - Brighton - Hove - Portslade - Mile Oak</timetableDescription>
      <timetableFilename>timetable_635314361868081863_0.xml</timetableFilename>
      <timetableId>10317</timetableId>
      <timetableName>1 1A Whitehawk - Mile Oak</timetableName>
      <timetable_stop />
      <validDates />
    </Timetable>
  </timetables>
  <validDestination>Mile Oak</validDestination>
</Route>
<Route z:Id="i14">

 <dateEffectiveFrom>2012-09-01T00:00:00</dateEffectiveFrom>
  <dateEffectiveTo i:nil="true" />
  <isLive>true</isLive>
  <relativePosition>0</relativePosition>
  <routeDescription i:nil="true" />
  <routeId>1235</routeId>
  <routeMap>
    <RouteMap z:Id="i16">
       <routeLineCenterLat>50.82936</routeLineCenterLat>
      <routeLineCenterLng>-0.1599884</routeLineCenterLng>
      <routeLineColour>#0000FF</routeLineColour>
      <routeLineFilename i:nil="true" />
      <routeLineInitialZoom>12</routeLineInitialZoom>
      <routeMapId>383</routeMapId>
      <routeMapName>1 Mile Oak - Whitehawk</routeMapName>
      <routeReference xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses">
        <a:EntityKey z:Ref="i15" xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data" />
      </routeReference>
    </RouteMap>
  </routeMap>
  <routeName>1 Mile Oak - Whitehawk</routeName>
  <route_stop />
  <route_stop_stop />
  <route_stop_timetable_stop />
  <service z:Ref="i1" />
   <timetables>
    <Timetable z:Id="i18">

      <dateAdded>2013-08-27T13:22:26.72</dateAdded>
      <daysOfWeek>Sundays and Public Holidays</daysOfWeek>
      <isLive>false</isLive>
      <relativePosition>2</relativePosition>
      <route z:Ref="i14" />
      <routeReference xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses">
        <a:EntityKey z:Ref="i15" xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data" />
      </routeReference>
      <route_stop_timetable_stop />
      <timetableDescription>Mile Oak - Portslade - Hove - Brighton - County Hospital - Whitehawk</timetableDescription>
      <timetableFilename>timetable_635132065412586254_1.xml</timetableFilename>
      <timetableId>10122</timetableId>
      <timetableName>1 1A Mile Oak - Whitehawk</timetableName>
      <timetable_stop />
      <validDates i:nil="true" />
    </Timetable>
    <Timetable z:Id="i20">

      <dateAdded>2014-03-26T13:09:06.297</dateAdded>
      <daysOfWeek>Mondays to Fridays</daysOfWeek>
      <isLive>false</isLive>
      <relativePosition>0</relativePosition>
      <route z:Ref="i14" />
      <routeReference xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses">
        <a:EntityKey z:Ref="i15" xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data" />
      </routeReference>
      <route_stop_timetable_stop />
      <timetableDescription>Mile Oak - Portslade - Hove - Brighton - County Hospital - Whitehawk</timetableDescription>
      <timetableFilename>timetable_635314361366540988_1.xml</timetableFilename>
      <timetableId>10316</timetableId>
      <timetableName>1 1A Mile Oak - Whitehawk</timetableName>
      <timetable_stop />
      <validDates />
    </Timetable>
    <Timetable z:Id="i22">

      <dateAdded>2014-03-26T13:09:53.047</dateAdded>
      <daysOfWeek>Saturdays</daysOfWeek>
      <isLive>false</isLive>
      <relativePosition>1</relativePosition>
      <route z:Ref="i14" />
      <routeReference xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Objects.DataClasses">
        <a:EntityKey z:Ref="i15" xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data" />
      </routeReference>
      <route_stop_timetable_stop />
          <timetableDescription>Mile Oak - Portslade - Hove - Brighton - County Hospital - Whitehawk</timetableDescription>
      <timetableFilename>timetable_635314361868081863_1.xml</timetableFilename>
      <timetableId>10318</timetableId>
      <timetableName>1 1A Mile Oak - Whitehawk</timetableName>
      <timetable_stop />
      <validDates />
    </Timetable>
  </timetables>
  <validDestination>Whitehawk, Brighton Stn</validDestination>
   </Route>
  </routes>
   <serviceAbbreviatedName />
  <serviceDescription>Whitehawk - County Hospital - City Centre - Hove - Portslade - Mile Oak</serviceDescription>

  <serviceId>1149</serviceId>
  <serviceName>1</serviceName>

  <serviceText>Whitehawk - Mile Oak</serviceText>

</Service>
```

Comment: Can you show what your XML looks like?

Comment: added more information. My aim is to get each of the timetables in a separate list like http://m.buses.co.uk/service.aspx?serviceid=1149

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides what @KooKiz already explained on how to safely check for `routeId` element value, your query also missed to use the required `XNamespace` for `routeId` element :

```
where (string)s.Element(ns+"routeId") == "1231"
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Side question am I in the right direction as I want to get each timetable out on it's own so it's clickable like the mobile website? 

I can use json if that's easier. But I am rather stuff

Comment: Yeah, I think you're in the right direction to get `timetable` in the next step

Comment: Ok, will have a go, if not will post it on here. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your query fails because not all `Route` nodes have a `routeId` child node. In that case, `s.Element("routeId")` returns null, and so an exception is thrown when trying to read the `Value` property. A convenient workaround is to cast the element to string instead of calling the `Value` property:

```
where (string)s.Element("routeId") == "1231"
```

Comment: Thanks, just tried this but I get no results. I get results when I remove it.

Comment: Also how can I make it so see if it contains a word with the node?